# How to deploy React Native web app using Expo in Node JS Azure - App Service

Tags: azure, react-native, azure-web-app-service, expo

When I deploy the application in Azure with Visual Studio Code, I get the following error stack:

`2020-10-28T20:34:32.249Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container appdemo_xxxxxx for site appdemo_xxxxxx 2020-10-28T20:34:37.841Z ERROR - Container appdemo_xxxxxx for site appdemo_xxxxxx has exited, failing site start 2020-10-28T20:34:37.844Z ERROR - Container appdemo_xxxxxx didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, failing site start. See container logs for debugging. 2020-10-28T20:34:37.874Z INFO  - Stopping site appdemo_xxxxxx because it failed during startup.`

The Plan de App Service is a SO Linux.

If I change start in **package.json** to `"node index.js"` work fine, but if I use this, not work:

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "jest --watchAll"
  },
```

I have created the variables in **Configuration** -> **App Settings** `PORT = 8080` and `WEBSITES_PORT = 80`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for this error:

1. Export the project from the VS terminal: `expo build:web --no-pwa`
2. Transfer it using **FTP** to Azure
3. Ready!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the PORT setting and change your WEBSITES_PORT to 8080. The start command [should be picked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-nodejs?pivots=platform-linux#run-custom-command) up from your "start" script in your `package.json`. If that isn't working, you can try setting `npm expo start` as a start-up command under Application Settings blade in the portal or use Azure CLI command `az webapp config set --resource-group <resource-group-name> --name <app-name> --startup-file "npm expo start"`. Also make sure your expo dependencies are being installed correctly. You should be able to verify in your deployment logs. If not, you can [customize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-nodejs?pivots=platform-linux#customize-build-automation) a pre-startup batch command to run your necessary npm install command.